# Slack-API - How to receive button click from a block? Getting error "This App responded with status Code 404"

Tags: python, flask, slack-api, slack-block-kit

I am creating a slack bot, which has a slash command that processes some data. The slash command responds with a confirmation block. The slash command handling works as expected, I am receiving the users' data and I can respond to it, but when I click on the yes/no buttons I get "This App responded with status Code 404".

```
from flask import Flask, Response, jsonify
from flask import request
from slackeventsapi import SlackEventAdapter
import os
from threading import Thread
from slack import WebClient
import json



# This `app` represents your existing Flask app
app = Flask(__name__)

SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET = os.environ['SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET']
slack_token = os.environ['SLACK_BOT_TOKEN']
VERIFICATION_TOKEN = os.environ['VERIFICATION_TOKEN']

# instantiating slack client
slack_client = WebClient(slack_token)


@app.route("/")
def event_hook(request):
    json_dict = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
    print(f"event hook: json_dict {json_dict}")
    if json_dict["token"] != VERIFICATION_TOKEN:
        return {"status": 403}

    if "type" in json_dict:
        if json_dict["type"] == "url_verification":
            response_dict = {"challenge": json_dict["challenge"]}
            return response_dict
    return {"status": 500}


slack_events_adapter = SlackEventAdapter(
    SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET, "/slack/events", app
)




def get_confirmation_block(confirmation_text: str, command_id: str):
    return [
        {
            "type": "header",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "New request",
                                "emoji": True
                    }
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
                    "fields": [
                        {
                            "type": "mrkdwn",
                            "text": "*Type:*\nPaid Time Off"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "mrkdwn",
                            "text": "*Created by:*\n<example.com|Fred Enriquez>"
                        }
                    ]
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
                    "fields": [
                        {
                            "type": "mrkdwn",
                            "text": "*When:*\nAug 10 - Aug 13"
                        }
                    ]
        },
        {
            "type": "actions",
                    "elements": [
                        {
                            "type": "button",
                            "text": {
                                    "type": "plain_text",
                                "emoji": True,
                                "text": "Approve"
                            },
                            "style": "primary",
                            "value": "click_me_123"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "button",
                            "text": {
                                    "type": "plain_text",
                                "emoji": True,
                                "text": "Reject"
                            },
                            "style": "danger",
                            "value": "click_me_123"
                        }
                    ]
        }
    ]




@app.route("/slack/events", methods=["POST"])
def message_actions():
    # Parse the request payload
    message_action = json.loads(request.form["payload"])
    user_id = message_action["user"]["id"]
    print(message_action)
    print("HERE") # I don't receive this
    return {"", 200}


@app.route("/slack/add_data", methods=["POST"])
def handle_slash_command():
    data = request.form
    print(data)
    channel_id = data["channel_id"]
    text = data['text'].strip()

    # Interactive message with confirmation buttons
    confirmation_text = f'Received: {text}\nDo you want to add this?'
    confirmation_block = get_confirmation_block(confirmation_text,
                                                "add_smth_confirmation")

    slack_client.chat_postMessage(channel=channel_id,
                                  blocks=confirmation_block,
                                  )

    return Response(status=200)


# Start the server on port 3000
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=3000)
```

[This is what I see in the channel - the 404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWDnZ.png)

I can't find a similar error and I read the slack-api docs. And /slack/events is setup as the Request URL in Interactivity settings.